# Does ReadOnly(true) work with Html.EditorForModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, readonly-attribute

Consider the following setup:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int ProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication4.Models.Product>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Product
            {
                ProductID = 1,
                Name = "Banana"
            });
    }
}
```

There result is this:
[image]

I was expecting that the `ProductID` property was not going to be editable via the `ReadOnly(true)` attribute. Is this supported? If not is there any way to hint ASP.NET MVC that some properties of my model are read-only? I would not like to just hide `ProductID` via `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ReadOnly` and `Required` attributes will be consumed by the metadata provider but won't be used. If you want to get rid of the input with `EditorForModel` you'll need a custom template, or `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`.

For custom template `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Product.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<Product>" %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProductID) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductID, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

Also note that the default model binder won't copy a value into a property with `[ReadOnly(false)]`. This attribute won't influence the UI rendered by the default templates.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. Too bad I don't want to use [ScaffoldColumn(false)] and creating an editor template would kind of defeat the purpose...

Comment: Well @naso, there are moments like this when we simply curse at Microsoft and continue with our daily jobs :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by adding a UIHintAttribute to the property on my class of "**ReadOnly**".

```
[UIHint("ReadOnly")]
public int ClassID { get; set; }
```

Then I simply added a **~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ReadOnly.ascx** file to my project with this in it:

```
<%= Model %>
```

A really simple way to add custom templates, you could include formatting or whatever.

Comment: An even cooler method could be to subclass the **DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider** class like in [Brad Wilson's post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html) and simply add this line:
`if (metadata.IsReadOnly) metadata.TemplateHint = "ReadOnly";`
Combined with the ReadOnly.ascx file in my post, this should make the ReadOnly(true) attribute work like you would expect. ASP.NET MVC rocks!

Comment: I know this is old, but the technique works. However, it might result in data being erased. My ReadOnly.cshtml is : @Model
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model) to ensure the value is always returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<Product>" %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProductID) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductID, new { @readonly = true }) %>

<%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
```