# MVC 4 Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata, data-annotations

I am using Data Annotations in my MVC 4 project with Scaffolding Nuget to create CRUD views. I am using Layer level Database model not EF.

So my Class look like as below:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))] 
public partial class UserProfile: IBrObject
{
     public UserProfile(string aspUserName): this()
        {
            this.AspUserName = aspUserName;
        }

     public string AspUserName { get; set; }
     public DateTime MetaDateFirstSaved { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMetaData
{
            [ReadOnly(true)]             
            [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
            [DisplayName("ASP UserName")]
            public object AspUserName { get; set; }
           [DisplayName("Date First Saved")]
           [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public object MetaDateFirstSaved { get; set; }
}
```

when i am trying to create views with Scaffolding Nuget it still shows AspUserName column not hide or not read only.
How i can hide or readonly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does ReadOnly(true) work with Html.EditorForModel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510081/does-readonlytrue-work-with-html-editorformodel)

Comment: "Mystere Man" uihint attribute might be right choice. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use `object` in metadata and `string` and `DateTime` respectively in actual view model so they don't match.

**Update**

Another possibility (*I pretty sure this is what's happening in your case*) is because your model type in the view defined as Interface type rather than class type.

In your view replace `@model IBrObject` with `@model UserProfile`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I looked from following sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted once your question is resolved. Thanks

Comment: Upped your response instead of repeating your response.

Comment: @MuhammadImran Why not mark answer is right one (its been a year)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

object AspUserName != string AspUserName